# Django Media Uploads with AWS S3 on Heroku TypeError

Tags: django, heroku, amazon-s3, media

I have a Django app hosted on Heroku and I am trying to upload media files to AWS S3 buket. When I upload i get the error "cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects"

## Settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'storages',
    ...
]

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
S3_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'MyBucketName'
S3_URL = 'https://%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % S3_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'

MEDIA_URL = S3_URL + '/media/'
```

## Error Page

```
Django Version:     1.9.5
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    

cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects

Exception Location:     /app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/connection.py in build_auth_path, line 94

....
....

        else:

            return self.get_bucket_server(server, bucket)

    def build_auth_path(self, bucket, key=''):

        key = boto.utils.get_utf8_value(key)

        path = ''

        if bucket != '':

 --->       path = '/' + bucket

        return path + '/%s' % urllib.parse.quote(key)

    def build_path_base(self, bucket, key=''):

        key = boto.utils.get_utf8_value(key)

        return '/%s' % urllib.parse.quote(key)
```

Comment: You must be calling `build_auth_path` without setting `bucket` somewhere. Can you give the `bucket` argument a default value, as you have with `key`?

Answer (score 0):

The error explains that you cannot perform string concatenation of a string '/' and an object which value is None. Check 'bucket' variable value.

Comment: How do I set the bucket variable ? as a string in the settings file or as an environment variable on heroku ?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem as I named the variable S3_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME and it should've been AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME